# What does -include mean when using g++

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, g++

I am trying to understand how  my makefile works and have come accross the following command:

g++ -g -Wall -O3 -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-variable -O0 -std=c++11 runAlgo.cpp bfs.cpp Node.cpp distribution.cpp resultSet.cpp -include 8puzzle.c -o 8puzzle.bfs

What does the -include part mean?

Answer (score 0):

> What does the -include part mean?

According to man gcc:

> ...
>
> -include file
>
> Process file as if "#include "file"" appeared as the first line of the primary source file.
>
> ...

So in your case content of `8puzzle.c` is added at the beginning of `runAlgo.cpp`.

You can check it using `-save-temps` option and explore `runAlgo.ii` preprocessed file.